# Speed of ball travelling around a circle

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

How can time be measured in $\pi$?

I'm going through Gilbert Strang's book "Calculus" and there's this diagram there:

[image]

It says in the book:

Important point: The distance around the circle (its circumference) is $2\pi r=2\pi$ because the radius is 1. The ball travels a distance $2\pi$ in a time $2\pi$. The speed equals 1.

How can time by measured in $\pi$ and not second or hours?

Comment: You call it $\pi$ units of time. Pick a unit. It could be seconds. It could be hours. It could be the amount of time needed to consume an entire pie. There is a unit, it is just unstated.

Answer (score 1):

In mathematical formulas describing physical phenomena distances appear as $a$, times as $T$, and forces as ${\bf F}$, etcetera. In these formulas the $a$, $T$, or ${\bf F}$ are variables for real numbers or vectors in ${\mathbb R}^3$. But there is a lot of background "mathematical-philosophical" work behind this: For each "physical dimension" (length, time, mass, energy, $\ldots$) one has chosen a unit, say, [m] (meter) for length, and these units correspond in a coherent way, such that, e.g., $${\bf F}=m\,{\bf a}\ $$ where ${\bf F}$, $m$, ${\bf a}$ denote the resulting numerical values of force, mass, and acceleration in the envisaged situation.

In your example Strang has chosen the time unit such that the ball traverses the circumference of the unit circle with speed $1$, hence makes the length $2\pi$ in $2\pi$ time units.